# IAP callback url

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

Upgrading from 2.6.1 to 5.x.  We have IAP Callback url setup in the HW Dashboard, and the callback url is working fine with 2.6.1 consumable iap.

Testing 5.x right now and successful purchase doesn't seem to send our server a callback for the purchase.  Does something need to be explicitly configured for the callback to work with 5.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Products with callback are subscriptions, and only subscriptions have callbacks.

The callback function of 5.x needs to be configured in AGC. For details, see [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-notifications-about-subscription-events-0000001050706084-V5?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: I am not referring to subscription notification url, i am referring to callback URL from service information. https://ibb.co/zbT4RHt

Comment: I am guessing the callback url is deprecated in 5.x?  If that is the case, we will just consume the token on server side when client passes it to server for validation.

Comment: Yes, callback url is deprecated in 5.x. It is recommended that the service logic be written based on the 5.x document. The application-level AT on the server and purchaseToken for verifying products need be written based on the 5.x document.pls kindly refer this [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/dev-guide-0000001050130254-V5).

Answer (score 0):

HMS 2.6.1 has been deprecated and HMS 5.0.X is drastically different than 2.6.1, please refer to the callback server sample codes for HMS 5.0 [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Examples-V5/server-sample-code-0000001050145549-V5).

There are Java, PHP, C#, Python, NodeJS, Golang, Ruby, Perl sample codes for your reference. Please review your current server code and apply the necessary changes.

Here is the reference for IAP server to your server notification [reference](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-notifications-about-subscription-events-0000001050706084-V5) . Your server must has HTTPS to receive the notification.

[image]

Comment: As per my initial post, the callback is working with 2.6.1 consumable iap and this wasn't code side configuration.  The image you posted refers to "Subscription" notification and I am refering to Callback URL (https://ibb.co/zbT4RHt).